# C# Generics Constraints with Interfaces to Decouple an API

Tags: c#, generics

In writing a data access layer, I want to decouple my public facing API from the concrete db implementations. For example, let's suppose that I want to use either MongoDb or Cassandra for my backing store.

So, what I want is for my C# code to utilize *IThingDao* through a factory method, etc. The factory will correspond to the actual implementation.

I have some very rudimentary interface and class samples to demonstrate what I hope to achieve. Unfortunately for me, this code generates numerous compile time errors saying the classes don't implement the members of the interface.

The following define my data objects:

```
public interface IBase
{
    Object Id { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }    
}

public interface IBaseMongoDb : IBase
{
    // Common MongoDb related things used by all concrete implementations
}

public interface IBaseCassandra : IBase
{
    // Common Cassandra related things used by all concrete implementations
}

public interface IThing : IBase
{
    String Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractBase
{
    public virtual Object Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractMongoDbBase : AbstractBase
{
    [BsonId]
    public override Object Id { get; set; }

    // Other specific MongoDb stuff
}

public abstract class AbstractCassandraBase : AbstractBase
{
    // Cassandra related stuff
}

public class ThingMongoDbImpl : AbstractMongoDbBase, IThing, IBaseMongoDb
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class ThingCassandraImpl : AbstractCassandraBase, IThing, IBaseCassandra
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

There are separate base abstracts for MongoDb and Cassandra data objects because each implementation has common features (such as annotations, etc) specific to one versus the other.

Here are the data access interfaces:

```
public interface IDao<T>
{
    T Save( T a_Value );
    void Update( T a_Value );
    void Delete( T a_Value );
    T Find( Object a_Key );
}

public interface IThingDao : IDao<IThing>
{
    IThing FindByName( String a_Name );
}
```

Here are the implementations for MongoDb and Cassandra:

```
public abstract class AbstractMongoDbDao<T> where T : IBaseMongoDb, new()
{
    public T Save( T a_Value )
    {
        // Save
        return a_Value;
    }
    public void Update( T a_Value )
    {
        // Update
    }
    public void Delete( T a_Value )
    {
        // Delete
    }
    public T Find( Object a_Key )
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class ThingDaoMongoDbImpl : AbstractMongoDbDao<ThingMongoDbImpl>, IThingDao
{
    public IThing FindByName( String a_Name )
    {
        // Do the lookup and return value
        return new ThingMongoDbImpl();
    }
}


public abstract class AbstractCassandraDao<T> where T : IBaseCassandra, new()
{
    public T Save( T a_Value )
    {
        // Save
        return a_Value;
    }
    public void Update( T a_Value )
    {
        // Update
    }
    public void Delete( T a_Value )
    {
        // Delete
    }
    public T Find( Object a_Key )
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class ThingDaoCassandraImpl : AbstractCassandraDao<ThingCassandraImpl>, IThingDao
{
    public IThing FindByName( String a_Name )
    {
        // Do the lookup and return value
        return new ThingCassandraImpl();
    }
}
```

For this code, *ThingDaoMongoDbImpl* and *ThingDaoCassandraImpl* generate the following compile time errors:

```
Error   1   'generics.decouple.ThingDaoMongoDbImpl' does not implement interface member 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Find(object)'. 'generics.decouple.AbstractMongoDbDao<generics.decouple.ThingMongoDbImpl>.Find(object)' cannot implement 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Find(object)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'generics.decouple.IThing'.
Error   2   'generics.decouple.ThingDaoMongoDbImpl' does not implement interface member 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Delete(generics.decouple.IThing)' C:\Projects\EDC\modules\EXCHANGES\CAD2CAD.Net\Z\Generics.cs 95  18  Z
Error   3   'generics.decouple.ThingDaoMongoDbImpl' does not implement interface member 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Update(generics.decouple.IThing)' C:\Projects\EDC\modules\EXCHANGES\CAD2CAD.Net\Z\Generics.cs 95  18  Z
Error   4   'generics.decouple.ThingDaoMongoDbImpl' does not implement interface member 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Save(generics.decouple.IThing)'   C:\Projects\EDC\modules\EXCHANGES\CAD2CAD.Net\Z\Generics.cs 95  18  Z
Error   5   'generics.decouple.ThingDaoCassandraImpl' does not implement interface member 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Find(object)'. 'generics.decouple.AbstractCassandraDao<generics.decouple.ThingCassandraImpl>.Find(object)' cannot implement 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Find(object)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'generics.decouple.IThing'.
Error   6   'generics.decouple.ThingDaoCassandraImpl' does not implement interface member 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Delete(generics.decouple.IThing)'   C:\Projects\EDC\modules\EXCHANGES\CAD2CAD.Net\Z\Generics.cs 126 18  Z
Error   7   'generics.decouple.ThingDaoCassandraImpl' does not implement interface member 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Update(generics.decouple.IThing)'   C:\Projects\EDC\modules\EXCHANGES\CAD2CAD.Net\Z\Generics.cs 126 18  Z
Error   8   'generics.decouple.ThingDaoCassandraImpl' does not implement interface member 'generics.decouple.IDao<generics.decouple.IThing>.Save(generics.decouple.IThing)' C:\Projects\EDC\modules\EXCHANGES\CAD2CAD.Net\Z\Generics.cs 126 18  Z
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of things that seem to be incorrect here, and this may be too broad for a simple answer. For example, in your `AbstractMongoDbDao<T>` class, your methods take and return the parameter T, which is limited to a `IBaseMongoDb`. Is that what you meant? To save and return a `IBaseMongoDb`? Or do you want to have something like `public TValue Save<TValue>(TValue value) {...}`?

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks for answering. Yes, I meant to constrain with IBaseMongoDb because those data objects have things in them specific to MongoDb, such as the BSON annotations.

Comment: I see a lot of duplicate code. `IBase->IBaseMongoDb` and `AbstractBase->AbstractMongoDbBase` both have same properties and are implemented and Dervied in `ThingMongoDbImpl`. Don't knw what made you do that? But these duplication can be avoided. Also *avoid* properties in `Interfaces` when you have abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThingDaoMongoDbImpl : AbstractMongoDbDao<ThingMongoDbImpl>, IThingDao
{
    public IThing FindByName( String a_Name )
    {
        // Do the lookup and return value
        return new ThingMongoDbImpl();
    }

     T Save( T a_Value ) { //implement it
     }
     void Update( T a_Value ) { 
     //implement it here
     }
     void Delete( T a_Value ) { // implement it here}
     T Find( Object a_Key ) { //implement it}
}
```

You are getting the compile time error because you did not implement the method of `IThingDao` interface.
your `public interface IThingDao : IDao<IThing>`, extends from IDao so you have to implement the methods of `IDao<IThing>` also

UPDATE

```
  public class ThingCassandraImpl : AbstractCassandraBase, IThing, IBaseCassandra, IThingDao
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public IThing Save(IThing a_Value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Update(IThing a_Value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Delete(IThing a_Value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IThing Find(object a_Key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IThing FindByName(string a_Name)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public abstract class AbstractCassandraDao<T> where T : IBaseCassandra,IThingDao, new() 
    {
        public T Save(T a_Value)
        {
            // Save
            return a_Value;
        }
        public void Update(T a_Value)
        {
            // Update
        }
        public void Delete(T a_Value)
        {
            // Delete
        }
        public T Find(Object a_Key)
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }

    public class ThingDaoCassandraImpl : AbstractCassandraDao<ThingCassandraImpl>
    {
        public IThing FindByName(String a_Name)
        {
            // Do the lookup and return value
            return new ThingCassandraImpl();
        }

        public IThing Save(IThing a_Value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Update(IThing a_Value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Delete(IThing a_Value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IThing Find(object a_Key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The two Abstract Dao's have those methods you are referring to. That's why I put them in the abstract classes to all other subclasses would automatically acquire them. Is that not correct?

Comment: No its not correct. See my update. Interfaces must be implemented